# Sending mail via SMTP using TLS

Tags: haskell, smtp, smtpclient

Does anybody know of any good libraries I can use to send a mail via SMTP from Haskell? I found `SMTPClient` and `HaskellNet`. The former does not support `TLS` and the latter does not seem to have examples for using TLS to send an email via SMTP. Did anybody manage to do that?

Comment: Not an answer, but some I've added info that might be useful here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311036/using-tls-extra-for-simple-smtp

Comment: @mhwombat, thank you. it look like the support is not there yet. But, I am sure it exists in some form in hackage where it just needs to be tweaked.

Comment: Have yo tried: (HaskellNet-SSL)[http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaskellNet-SSL-0.1.1.1].

Comment: Though I didn't try it myself, you might want to take a look at [hs-tls](https://github.com/vincenthz/hs-tls) and [hs-connection](https://github.com/vincenthz/hs-connection). The latter looks quite promising for solving your problem.

Comment: Are you asking about sending SMTP in general, or is there something particular with Google that is causing problems?

Comment: @thecoshman, it is the TLS part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read This Pages :
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaskellNet-SSL-0.2.1/docs/Network-HaskellNet-SMTP-SSL.html

Easily Connector :)
https://github.com/dpwright/HaskellNet-SSL

Maybe this can help you!

Set Your Username And Password:

By send commands

```
sendCommand :: SMTPConnection -> Command -> IO (ReplyCode, ByteString)
```